# ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'easy_install') not found

Tags: python, shell, python-2.7, easy-install

I'm trying to install a package and one of the instructions is the following, but I get an error.

```bsh
easy_install -U distribute pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/easy_install", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('distribute', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.4.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 351, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-3.4.1-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2362, in load_entry_point
    raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group,name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'easy_install') not found
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Looking at other similar questions I still haven't figured out the solution but it seems to be some Python version or installation clash?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is likely multiple installed versions, stemming from installing via aptitude and pip/easy_install. This helped me:

```
pip uninstall <package>
sudo pip uninstall <package>
sudo aptitude remove <package>
```

then reinstall it...

Answer (score 1):

So I just got this error too and I thought I would add this just in case anyone else stumbles on to this question. I tried uninstalling the pip with sudo and without and it still wasn't working. I looked at the path and it looks like the pip was being accessed from my trash bin I cleared my trash bin and my pip started working without any problems. I also checked searched my laptop through finder to make sure I deleted all instances of my pip throughout except for my project folder. It