# ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'pip') not found on Mac

Tags: pip, upgrade, importerror

I got the message

`You are using pip version 8.0.2, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.`

When I try to install a package through pip.

I followed the instruction and upgrade pip with `pip install --upgrade pip`. Now I'm getting an error with pip, even with `pip --version` to check the version of pip.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==8.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 357, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 2393, in load_entry_point
    raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group,name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'pip') not found
```

I've searched online and found some similar issues like, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19427486/pip-importerror-entry-point-console-scripts-pip-not-found), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871218/importerror-entry-point-console-scripts-easy-install-not-found) and [this](https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/26900). but none of the solutions worked for me.

I think it might be I have multiple version of pip on my Mac, how can I clean it up and get the latest version installed, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Manually removed all pip repositories in `/usr/local/bin/`. (not sure if it's necessary.)

Then reinstall pip following the instructions [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/).

> To install pip, securely download get-pip.py.
>
> Then run the following:
>
> `python get-pip.py`

FYI, `easy-install pip` doesn't work.